# Reduce memory usage after opening query with many records

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-xe8

I did a small test project where I have an FDConnection component (connected to a MySQL database) and an FDQuery, the FDQuery menu SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM products
```

This query brings 6000 records.
When I run my test the memory used is 2MB (when starting the query it remains closed).
I have a TButton that has the following code:

```
if qrProducts.Active then
   qrProducts.Refresh
else
   qrProducts.Open;
```

When clicking on the button once, the memory goes up to 12MB, then with each click that I give again, the memory goes up 1.5MB until reaching approximately 30MB.
I have another TButton that has the following code:

```
qrProducts.Close;
```

When closing the query the memory usage drops to 21MB.

This behavior is normal, would it be a Firedac cache? I was wondering what can be done to get the system back to the initial 2MB, if it can be done?

Comment: It is likely to be a MySQL client cache, not FireDac related. If it is cache, no need to worry, the 21MB will be reused during the next queries, and the RAM consumption shouldn't increase. Try to instantiate via CreatE/Free the instance to see if it changes something in respect to Close.

Comment: When I instantiate TFDQuery via Create and after the consultation I give a Free, the behavior is the same.

Comment: Client cache is held as long as the connection to MySQL is open. Close it with something like `qrProducts.Connection.Close;`.  Not a good idea to keep opening and closing the connection just so you can see lower memory usage between queries however.

Comment: Have you tried running the Delphi memory manager with fulldebugmode set?

Comment: I used MadExcept to see if there is a memory leak, but it doesn't.

Comment: How do you check memory usage? Task manager is not accurate, because it shows what the OS has reserved for your application, which might be more than your app requested, and it only goes down in big chunks.

Comment: MadExcept is not a memory leak test tool. It's an exception handling tool. If you're not getting an exception, MadExcept is useless in this situation.

Comment: If it is tied to the connection, just ignore this 21MB RAM consumption. It will be reused for the next query. FireDac doesn't leak memory. We are not in 1990 any more. If you need every bit of memory, don't use a SQL database.